Right Cross Validation Implementation (Regression)
I am very new to machine learning and i am starting to work my way up. I have made an implementation for cross validation which will be used with ensemble models later. I have made a pipeline in sklearn to do all the necessary preprocessing steps on the data.
def cross_validation(data_train, data_test, regressor, cv):
    X_train = data_train.copy()
    y_train = X_train.pop("<target>")
    
    X_test = data_test.copy()
    
    # To store training & validation RMSE for each K Fold iteration
    train_rmse = pandas.Series(numpy.zeros(cv.get_n_splits()))
    val_rmse = pandas.Series(numpy.zeros(cv.get_n_splits()))
    
    val_predictions = pandas.Series(numpy.zeros(X_train.shape[0]))                     
    test_predictions = pandas.Series(numpy.zeros(X_test.shape[0]))
    
    for fold, (train_idx, val_idx) in enumerate(cv.split(X_train, y_train)):
        model = clone(regressor)
        
        X_train_fold = X_train.iloc[train_idx].reset_index(drop=True)
        y_train_fold = y_train.iloc[train_idx].reset_index(drop=True)
        
        X_val_fold = X_train.iloc[val_idx].reset_index(drop=True)
        y_val_fold = y_train.iloc[val_idx].reset_index(drop=True)
        
        model.fit(X_train_fold, y_train_fold)
        
        y_train_fold_predictions = model.predict(X_train_fold)
        y_val_fold_predictions = model.predict(X_val_fold)
        
        val_predictions[val_idx] = y_val_fold_predictions
    
        train_fold_rmse = rmse(y_train_fold, y_train_fold_predictions)
        val_fold_rmse = rmse(y_val_fold, y_val_fold_predictions)
        
        train_rmse[fold] = train_fold_rmse
        val_rmse[fold] = val_fold_rmse
       
        print(f"Fold #{fold} - Training RMSE: {train_fold_rmse:.5f} | Validation RMSE: {val_fold_rmse:.5f}")
    
        y_test_predictions = model.predict(X_test)
        test_predictions += y_test_predictions
    
    print(f"Training Avg.RMSE: {numpy.mean(train_rmse):.5f} ± {numpy.std(train_rmse):.5f} | Validation Avg.RMSE: {numpy.mean(val_rmse):.5f} ± {numpy.std(val_rmse):.5f} | Out of Fold RMSE: {rmse(y_train, val_predictions):.5f}")
              
    test_predictions = test_predictions / cv.get_n_splits()
        
    return val_rmse, val_predictions, test_predictions

randomForest = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, criterion="squared_error", random_state=42)
randomForestPipe = make_pipeline(steps, randomForest)
scores["Random Forest"], oof_predictions["Random Forest"], test_predictions["Random Forest"] = cross_validation(data_train, data_test, randomForestPipe, skfcv)

I want to make sure weather the above implementation is right. Why do i have this doubt? Answer to that is due to training & validation RMSE score. On a dry run with RandomForestRegressor i am getting the following RMSE values
Fold #0 - Training RMSE: 33.65014 | Validation RMSE: 89.35102
Fold #1 - Training RMSE: 33.85028 | Validation RMSE: 88.65404
Fold #2 - Training RMSE: 33.83690 | Validation RMSE: 87.99569
Fold #3 - Training RMSE: 33.71045 | Validation RMSE: 89.18023
Fold #4 - Training RMSE: 33.86499 | Validation RMSE: 88.31499
Training Avg.RMSE: 33.78255 ± 0.08610 | Validation Avg.RMSE: 88.69920 ± 0.51007 | Out of Fold RMSE: 88.70065

The above values does not seem to be ideal based on my understanding. Please correct me if i am wrong. Any clarification and suggestions on necessary changes will be really helpful.
Thanks in advance :)
